# Genotype data simulation

Tags: genetics

I would like to simulate genotype data. The desired output file is plink map and ped file(bed bim fam is also fine). For each person, there are 10000 SNPs. Within the genotype data, two populations are required. I would like to generate 6000 individuals for the first population. I would like to generate another 4000 individuals for the second population. Then within the first population, the 6000 individuals are paired into 3000 couples randomly. Each couple has two children, the child genotype are generated by gene dropping. Within the second population, the 4000 individuals are paired into 2000 couples randomly. Each couple has two children, the child genotype are generated by gene dropping. Finally, I want to have a plink map and ped file with 20000 individuals, each individual has 10000 SNPs.

Comment: And the question or problem is? And you are using lots of jargon and terminology that is specific to genetic algorithm optimization. Either find place where that is common or provide explanations for terms you are using.